# Display an url image in column from a lookup

Tags: lookup-column, image-display

i'm struggling for several days now to create an image column comming from a lookup table.

I have my main Sharepoint list with one column called Image_Thumbnail.
I want user to only put an image coming from a controlled sources, so i create a second list
With 2 columns (Title and URL)

The logic I had in mind is that the user will search with the lookup into the second table and after selection the image will appear in the cell.
I'm not very familiar with SharePoint and JSON column formatter, and would appreciate some help.
Thanks a lot